# method stubbing on before(:all)

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

```
require './spec/spec_helper'
require './bank'

describe Bank do
  context "#transfer" do
    before(:all) do
      @customer1 = Customer.new(500)
      customer2 = Customer.new(0)
      @customer1.stub(:my_money).and_return(1000)
      customer2.stub(:my_money).and_return(0)
      @transfer_message = Bank.new.transfer(@customer1, customer2, 2000)
    end 

    it "should return insufficient balance if transferred amount is greater than balance" do
      expect(@transfer_message).to eq("Insufficient funds")
    end 

    it "calls my_money" do
      expect(@customer1).to have_received(:my_money)
    end 
  end 
end
```

When I use `before(:each)` instead `before(:all)` it works. But if use `before(:all)` it throws error as `undefined method proxy_for for nil:NilClass`. I couldn't find out the reason. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As i remember `before(:all)` is depricated and replaced  by `before do ...` also is more proper way is do not use variables, you could use `let` instead. If you have nil:NilClass this means that rspec didn't create Customer record in database (it could be resolver by calling `let!(:object) { action }` ) Something like this.

Answer (score 21):

Late to the party? Yeah, but wouldn't mind to drop my own one cent from what I discovered. I encountered a similar error while trying to stub a request in a `RSpec.configure` block so that the stub will only be available to examples I pass the `config.around(:each, option)` option to.

So, that means I was using the stub outside the scope of individual examples which is not supported by `RSpec::Mocks` [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/scope)!. A work around is to use a temporary scope in the context.

So you have

```
before(:all) do
  RSpec::Mocks.with_temporary_scope do
    @customer1 = Customer.new(500)
    customer2 = Customer.new(0)
    @customer1.stub(:my_money).and_return(1000)
    customer2.stub(:my_money).and_return(0)
    @transfer_message = Bank.new.transfer(@customer1, customer2, 2000)
  end
end
```

HTH!

Comment: This is amazing and probably should be in core IMO, e.g. "when using a subset of tagged examples, this should be fine and be executed in a temporary scope".

Answer (score 9):

`before(:all)` is not deprecated, but use of doubles from rspec-mocks in `before(:all)` is not supported. See the referenced issues in [github issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/528) for background.

The current `master` version of rspec-mocks, to be available with 3.0.0.beta2, will fail with the following error:

```
The use of doubles or partial doubles from rspec-mocks outside of the per-test lifecycle is not supported.
```

Prior versions will generate the `undefined method proxy_for ...` error at the point of stubbing.

Comment: Out of curiosity could you tell me why they didn't support this prior rspec3?

Comment: Check out the links in the github issue and you'll get some background.

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
require "rspec/mocks/standalone"
before(:all) do
```

Comment: Careful. This started giving me more errors re-running my test cases: `SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint`. Maybe adding an explanation of what standalone does would be nice. Solved it by setting a `debugger` at the top of my test file, deleted all model records when it triggered using `Model.destroy_all`, and also had to delete sql_sequence using `Base.connection.execute`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's as canonical/best-practice as [@El'Magnifico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235269/method-stubbing-on-beforeall/35683938#35683938) using [`RSpec::Mocks.with_temporary_scope`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks#with_temporary_scope-class_method), but I found that by using an `around` hook instead of `before`, I was able to dynamically inject `before` blocks (and similar) into the `example_group`, resulting in them running alongside my test:

- https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/around-hooks

## Example

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ..snip..
  config.include RequestForgerySpecHelper, type: :feature
  # ..snip..
end

# spec/support/request_forgery_spec_helper.rb
module RequestForgerySpecHelper
  def self.included(base)
    base.around(:all) do |ex|
      puts "around all start"

      ex.example_group.prepend_before do
        puts "around all inside prepend_before"
      end

      ex.example_group.append_after do
        puts "around all inside append_after"
      end

      ex.run

      puts "around all end"
    end
  end
end
```

Now if we assume our test already prints some logs `before`, `after`, and inside the `test` itself, our output looks like this:

```
around all start
around all inside prepend_before
inside spec file before
inside spec file test
inside spec file after
around all inside append_after
around all end
```

Because we are now dynamically injecting our `before` hook into the same context as our tests, we no longer see the following error:

> `before` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block)

## Going Deeper

The `ex` parameter provided to the `around` hook is an instance of [`RSpec::Core::Example::Procsy`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Example/Procsy), which gives access to the [`RSpec::Core::Example`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Example) instance through the [`example`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Example/Procsy#example-instance_method) attribute.

`RSpec::Core::Example` gives us access to the `RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup` associated with this test via the [`example_group`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Example#example_group-instance_method) method.

`RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup` gives us access to the DSL/methods allowing us to dynamically define `before`/`after`/`let`/etc blocks without triggering the `not available from within an example` error; as we can see by listing the methods in pry:

```
ls RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup
# RSpec::Core::Hooks#methods: after  append_after  append_before  around  before  hooks  prepend_after  prepend_before
# RSpec::Core::MemoizedHelpers::ClassMethods#methods: let  let!  subject  subject!
# RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup.methods:
#  add_example           currently_executing_a_context_hook?  define_nested_shared_group_method  describe                            ensure_example_groups_are_configured  fcontext   ffeature              fit                    fspecify                              include_examples       location                 parent_groups   run                       scenario   specify                          superclass_metadata    update_inherited_metadata  xexample   xspecify
#  before_context_ivars  declaration_locations                delegate_to_metadata               described_class                     example                               fdescribe  file_path             focus                  id                                    it                     metadata                 pending         run_after_context_hooks   set_it_up  store_before_context_ivars       top_level?             with_replaced_metadata     xfeature
#  children              define_example_group_method          descendant_filtered_examples       description                         example_group                         feature    filtered_examples     for_filtered_examples  idempotently_define_singleton_method  it_behaves_like        next_runnable_index_for  remove_example  run_before_context_hooks  set_ivars  subclass                         top_level_description  xcontext                   xit
#  context               define_example_method                descendants                        each_instance_variable_for_example  examples                              fexample   find_and_eval_shared  fscenario              include_context                       it_should_behave_like  ordering_strategy        reset_memoized  run_examples              skip       superclass_before_context_ivars  traverse_tree_until    xdescribe                  xscenario
```