# FactoryGirl Factory not registered -- other SO posts not cutting it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

When I use Factory Girl to create an instance of my model class, it flakes out on using any dependent factory. So the below call:

```
@abc = FactorGirl.create(:abc)
```

results in

```
/user/path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:24:in `find': Factory not registered: environment (ArgumentError)
```

I've read every Stack Overflow post about this error message and can't find the answer. (I've even tried this, for the record: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/issues/120). Any help is much appreciated.

---

Model requires another model:

```
# /app/models/abc.rb
class Abc < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :environment
  validates :environment, presence: true
end
```

Factory tries to create instance of another model

```
# /spec/factories/abcs.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :abc do
    value "MyString"
    environment FactoryGirl.create(:environment) # The offending line
  end
end
```

Gemfile partial:

```
# Gemfile
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

And spec_helper.rb:

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235269/method-stubbing-on-beforeall
require 'rspec/mocks/standalone'
require 'support/controller_helpers'

require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start

# https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-12/docs/example-groups/shared-examples
# https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/407
Dir["./spec/concerns/**/*.rb"].sort.each {|f| require f}

require 'factory_girl_rails'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Database cleaner config truncated for space

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

end
```

Comment: Do you have factory for environment model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you try to use the `:environment` factory before it is defined. FactoryGirl loads its factory in alphabetical order, so factory `:abc` loads before `:environment`. Normally this is not an issue as factories should delay object creation, however you are not delaying anything and you call `FactoryGirl.create(:environment)` at the moment factory `abc` is being registered. Quick and dirty fix - make this execution to be delayed:

```
environment { FactoryGirl.create(:environment) } # Note the brackets
```

This way passed block will be executed when you actually building new object, so when all factories are already loaded.

That being said, you don't need that block at all. For one-to-one association you can simply do:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :abc do
    value "MyString"
    environment
  end
end
```

FactoryGirl is clever enough to figure out it is an association and that it is to use `:environment` factory. If you prefer to use different factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :punk_abc do
    value "MyString"
    association :environment, factory: :bad_environment
  end
end
```

Comment: Another issue is that when you do `environment FactoryGirl.create(:environment)` that would mean that `FactoryGirl.create(:environment)` is evaluated when the factory is defined. Not when instances are created - thus every instance of `abc` would share the same  `environment`. Which is usually not a desirable behavior.